# How to update the single UI thread with multiple downloading threads in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, windows-runtime

Could anyone please help me to update the single UI thread with multiple downloading threads? in C# with WinRT.

I'm currently using Task.Run. It works, but since it spreads to multiple threads processing, the program failed to update the single UI properly.

Method UpdateRSSItemAsync() downloads the content (it'll updates RSSItemList) that is binding to UI (ListView).

Thank you,

Program runs fine in sequential order

```
// Run multiple tasks in sequential order
foreach (SyndicationItem item in CurrentFeed.Items)
{
    if (m_bDownloadInterrupted)
        break;

    RssItemList = await UpdateRSSItemAsync(CurrentRSSDataGroup, RssItemList, CurrentFeed, item);

}
```

However, failed to update UI if running in multiple threads

```
// Run multiple tasks in multiple threads
foreach (SyndicationItem item in CurrentFeed.Items)
{
    if (m_bDownloadInterrupted)
        break;

    RssItemList = await Task.Run<List<RSSItem>>(async () =>
    {
        RssItemList = await UpdateRSSItemAsync(CurrentRSSDataGroup, RssItemList, CurrentFeed, item);
        return RssItemList;
    });
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You're changing the value of the property for every item in the `Items` list. This doesn't *seem* like it's what you'd really want to do.

Comment: Method UpdateRSSItemAsync() downloads the content (it'll updates RSSItemList) that is binding to UI (ListView). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Task.WhenAny` or [Stephen Toub's `Interleaved`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/08/02/processing-tasks-as-they-complete.aspx):

```
var tasks = CurrentFeed.Items.Select(item => UpdateRSSItemAsync(CurrentRSSDataGroup, RssItemList, CurrentFeed, item)).ToList();
while (tasks.Count != 0)
{
  var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
  tasks.Remove(completedTask);
  ProcessRssItem(await completedTask);
}
```

You may find my [`async` / `await` intro post helpful](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Comment: Thanks. but Task.WhenAll only returns results after all the downloads are completed right? I want content to be shown dynamically, show the individual content once it is ready and download from Internet.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to force breaking the process? I implement if (m_bDownloadInterrupted) break; in my code in case I need to break the process.

Comment: `CancellationTokenSource` is the standard way to cancel an asynchronous operation.